# laravel DB::transaction how to update records?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a function in a controller like this:

```
DB::transaction(function () use ($request) {
            for ($parts=0; $parts < count($request->name) ; $parts++) {
                $parts_info = new PartsInfo; 
                $parts_info -> part_id = $request -> id;
                $parts_info -> name = $request -> name[$parts];
                $parts_info -> qty = $request -> qty[$parts];
                $parts_info -> price = $request -> price[$parts];
                $parts_info -> save();
            }
        });
```

Now I want to update the records. How do I do that? Here multiple records have the same `part_id` which has a one-to-many relationship with another table.
Note: Tried using `$parts_info = PartsInfo::where('parts_id', $request->id)->get();` and without `get()`

Comment: try this without DB transactions and then check what is the error.
Also after that enclose that in Try catch block and check to see the particular exception

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
  DB::transaction(function () use ($request) {
        for ($parts=0; $parts < count($request->parts) ; $parts++) {
        
          PartsInfo::where("parts_id", $request->id)->update([
             "name" => $request->name[$parts],
              "qty" =>  $request->qty[$parts],
              "price" => $request->price[$parts]
            ]);

        }
    });
```

Comment: Already tried this.. doesn't work..

Comment: Ok then I think you need to print
$request->id
Check its value... Might be you update with wrong id .. please check it

Comment: ID is correct.. checked with dd.. don't know why it doesn't work... if I use 'updateOrCreate' it just creates a new record

Comment: it will have the issue if it is one to many relation and your your checking parts_id then what record will it actually update ?

Comment: yes, i have an one to many relation and I'm updating other attributes except of parts_id

Comment: then the best way is to delete the child records and then recreate it

Comment: Yes, deleting does solve the problem for now, but it creates new records so the timestamps() also changes. I need to find a solution for updating.